# Using an alias in a select statement in a join query

Tags: oracle

I am very new at using Oracle (in the class now). I have a problem with the query I am trying to run. I have researched a lot of other answers on this site and none of them seem to apply directly to my problem so the solutions aren't working.

I need to find the total amount spent on lunches by each employee.

Show first_name, last_name, credit_limit, and total_price_spent in your results.

Order the answer by total_price_spent in descending order. Only show the employees who spent more than their credit limit.

I figured out how to do everything but the part about `showing only the employees who spent more than their credit limit`. I tried to use a select statement at the end but discovered that I can't use an alias in a select statement so I don't really know where to go from here. Any help would be appreciated. This is what I have so far.

```
select a.first_name, a.last_name, credit_limit, sum(c.quantity * d.price) as total_price_spent
from l_employees a join l_lunches b on a.employee_id = b.employee_id join l_lunch_items c on b.lunch_id = c.lunch_id join l_foods d on c.supplier_id = d.supplier_id and c.product_code = d.product_code
group by a.first_name, a.last_name, a.credit_limit
order by total_price_spent desc;
```

Comment: Please show your table structures

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is a HAVING clause.  It's like a WHERE, but is used when you're using group by.  You want to drop it in between the group by and order by.  Something like 'HAVING total > a.credit_limit' should work.  If using the alias 'total' doesn't work (haven't tested this), you might have to do 'sum(c.quantity * d.price)' again in the HAVING clause instead of using total, so HAVING sum(c.quantity * d.price) > a.credit_limit.

Comment: Great, glad it worked!  Please accept this as the answer... help me get some rep! :)

Answer (score 2):

As Mike said : Add HAVING

```
select a.first_name, a.last_name, credit_limit, sum(c.quantity * d.price) as total_price_spent
from l_employees a join l_lunches b on a.employee_id = b.employee_id join l_lunch_items c on b.lunch_id = c.lunch_id join l_foods d on c.supplier_id = d.supplier_id and c.product_code = d.product_code
group by a.first_name, a.last_name, a.credit_limit
having sum(c.quantity * d.price) > credit_limit
order by total_price_spent desc;
```